# Java URL grab stock quote on timer

Tags: java, url, timer, finance

Someone suggested I post this in stackoverflow instead of stackexchange, so here I am. I'm trying to make a simple stock-ticker of sorts. Just experimenting with free time. Anyways, I'm trying to simply run the `main()` part of the following every 5 seconds (or whatever time):

This code works:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class URLConnectionReader {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
String[] stocks={"GOOG","MSFT"}; //
    URL yahoofinance = new URL("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv? 
s="+stocks[0]+"+"+stocks[1]+"&f=hg");
    URLConnection yc = yahoofinance.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
          in.close();
}
}
```

Now, I've tried incorporating the above into the time program below. Have tried throwing exceptions and playing with `try-catch` but I'm out of my element at this point. Let me know.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class StockPrinter {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //1- Taking an instance of Timer class.
    Timer timer = new Timer("Printer");

    //2- Taking an instance of class contains your repeated method.
    MyTask t = new MyTask();


    //TimerTask is a class implements Runnable interface so
    //You have to override run method with your certain code black

    //Second Parameter is the specified the Starting Time for your timer in
    //MilliSeconds or Date

    //Third Parameter is the specified the Period between consecutive
    //calling for the method.

    timer.schedule(t, 0, 2000);

}
}

class MyTask extends TimerTask {  /*extends implies that MyTask has all    
variables/properties of TimerTask */
//times member represent calling times.
private int times = 0;


public void run() {
   // String[] stocks={"GOOG","MSFT"};
    times++;


    if (times <= 5) {

 String[] stocks={"GOOG","MSFT"}; //
    URL yahoofinance = new URL("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?        

s="+stocks[0]+"+"+stocks[1]+"&f=hg");
     URLConnection yc = yahoofinance.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                yc.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        System.out.println(inputLine);
          in.close();        

    } else {
        System.out.println("Timer stops now...");

        //Stop Timer.
        this.cancel();
        System.exit(0); //added:should quit program

    }
}
}
```

Note: I've grabbed the main chunks of these codes from either Java's website or perhaps in some forum, so I apologize if any of it is recognised. Not passing the heavy lifting off as my own by any means. Just want to get this to work. Here are the compile errors:

```
StockPrinter.java:43: unreported exception java.net.MalformedURLException; must
be caught or declared to be thrown
    URL yahoofinance = new URL("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="+st
ocks[0]+"+"+stocks[1]+"&f=hg");
                       ^
StockPrinter.java:44: unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught o
r declared to be thrown
    URLConnection yc = yahoofinance.openConnection();
                                                  ^
StockPrinter.java:46: unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught o
r declared to be thrown
                                yc.getInputStream()));
                                                 ^
StockPrinter.java:48: unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught o
r declared to be thrown
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                                   ^
StockPrinter.java:50: unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught o
r declared to be thrown
          in.close();
                  ^
5 errors
```

Comment: So.. what problem are you having?

Comment: It seems everything goes to hell when I try to actually run the URL-grab in the `if` statement in `Run()`. That is, here is the full error list:

Comment: I'll edit and include it above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
        try
        {
            String[] stocks =
            {
                "GOOG", "MSFT"
            }; //
            URL yahoofinance = new URL("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + stocks[0] + "+" + stocks[1] + "&f=hg");
            URLConnection yc = yahoofinance.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    yc.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Oops bad things happens");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! Workd's great. I got it now. Ironically, I went back to the original program, and it seems to be working as well. As to WHY, well that honestly doesn't make much sense to me so I'll have to look over it some more, but your way makes sense so glad it works. Any reason there's no need to `catch` the MalURLException?

Comment: No need to catch MalURLException because it extends IOException.You could wrap the URL line in a try catch and then the URLConnection line in a try catch. or the put the whole block in a try catch as I did.

Comment: It also works in Groovy. I just had to rename "in" into "inp", as "in" is a reserved keyword in Groovy. By the way, "f=hg" shows the high/low for the day, not real-time data. See http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm for format options.

Answer (score 2):

The run method you define in "MyTask" does not throw any exceptions.
However, the code it executes DOES throw exceptions, such as "new URL()".

The reason it works in the Main is because it can rethrow any Exception.

Since these exceptions go unhandled, the compiler is (rightly) complaining about it.

You need to surround the offending calls with try/catch blocks.
For example:

```
URL yahoofinance = null;
try{
  yahoofinance = new URL( "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?" );
} catch( MalformedURLException ex ) {
  // print error or throw a new error or whatever
  throw new Error( "I cannot deal with this problem" );
}
```

Do similar things for each of the compilation exceptions in your post.

Comment: Yup. However, do you think that I'll be able to catch all of them? I troubleshooted by compiling line by line of the errors, and literally did exactly what you did above fo the MalformedURLException. However, not sure if the other one's are so simple?

Comment: So far it seems try-catch only works on the MalURl. It seems that the variables go undefined when trying to implement try-catch on the other. Hmm. Starting to wonder if there is another way around this problem. Is it possible to throw Exceptions on Run() method?

Comment: I don't think you can change the run() method signature to throw Exceptions, but you could throw runtime errors. You will need to define the variables outside the scope of the try block for them to be defined. I'll edit my example to reflect this.